# Is it possible to list and create custom post types with Vimpress?

Tags: custom-post-types

I just started using [vimpress](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1953). I can write posts by typing in Vim

```
:BlogNew
```

and send them by typing:

```
:BlogSend
```

I think a lot of Wordpress developers may be using the plugin.

So my question is Is it possible to list and create custom post types with Vimpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple and short.
up to vimpress latest version 0.91 which was developed at 2007-07-13 no you can't.